# Certain range of delay

Tags: verilog, fpga

I had issue with asynchronous signal which must be constrained from 2nS to 2.2nS. 
Set max delay and set min delay makes different result
set max delay interacts with setup time and set min delay interacts with hold time.
In this case I just need to put setup time it to specific range. Is it possible to do automatically?

Answer (score 0):

you can probably use `#(min:typ:max)` syntax for delays. It allows you to chose the delay model when you start simulation. The exact way depends on the simulator you use. i.e. synopsys provides for 'sdf' files to allow it.

an example from LRM 28.16.1

```
parameter min_hi = 97, typ_hi = 100, max_hi = 107;
logic clk;
always begin
   #(95:100:105) clk = 1;
   #(min_hi:typ_hi:max_hi) clk = 0;
end
```

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about a synthesis constraint, not simulation

Comment: Yes. You are right. For asynchronous processes I need very strict delays not more not less. I tried to do it by placing LUTs with LOC for small projects it's ok but for large...